# Wordpress loop being very slow page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following wordpress loop and it is taking forever to render the page its sticking on the circle in fire fox and was wondering if anyone new how to speed this page template up I am just using Advanced Cusotm Fields which shouldnt take this long to render.

Is there anything that sticks out at people would cause it take slow long to render the page. I also getting memory alocation issues with this script any help is greatly apreaciated.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Well Being Page Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
 ?>

 <?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php 
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'wellbeing',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_key'      => 'ip',
    'meta_value'    => $ip 
    );




// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$isFound=false;
?>

 <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>
 <?php $isFound=true;?> 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php $isFound=false;?> 
<p><?php 


_e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php

if($isFound==true )
{   

}else
{
// Gather post data.
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'Opt In',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_type'     => 'wellbeing',
'meta_key'      => 'ip',
    'meta_value'    => $ip,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);

// Insert the post into the database.
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+2 week');
$currentdate = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
// save a basic text value
$field_key = "expirey_date";
$twoweeksaway = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s');;
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

// save a basic text value
$field_key = "date_joined";
$value = $currentdate;
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// save a basic text value
$field_key = "ip";
$value = $ip;
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

// save a basic text value
$field_key = "email";
$value = wpse_email();
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );


};
?>

<?php
 $dateJoined=the_field('date_joined', $post_id );
 $expiredate=the_field('expirey_date', $post_id );

?>

<?php 
//we want to disable the option to opt out of well being
if($dateJoined >= $expiredate) { ?>
<div style="clear:both;">
Welcome this page allows you to opt out of our well being program. You have <?php $daysleft =currentdate -twoweeksaway; echo $daysleft;?> 

Do you wish to opt out of the well being program 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<form name="wellbeing" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form><?php }; ?>

 <?php wp_reset_query();     // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Test with `'numberposts'   => 10,` and see if it load quickly. Maybe you have too many posts.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte only one entrt

Comment: You have an issue here. `<?php endif; ?>` inside your while loop. Probably breaking your code.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte can you recomend a re write

Comment: @FelippeDuarte sorry how would it when its stoping the if where the while statement is ?

Comment: You have a `endif` but not `endwhile`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes i do here <?php endwhile; else: ?>

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to make your loop like this:

```
$isFound = false;
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $the_query->the_post();
        $isFound=true;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
enfif;
```

Without `the_post()` it does not work, and you have to `wp_reset_postdata()` to not influence the rest of the page.